# Iterate through LevelDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, leveldb

Can someone please educate me on this:

Trying to use levelDb in a node.js instance, to store the `name` key and the `ID` string against it, I want to be able to check if the `ID` is already in the DB so...

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/Level/levelup#dbcreatereadstreamoptions) I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I have `db.js` here:

```
var level = require('level');  
var path = require('path');

var dbPath = process.env.DB_PATH || path.join(__dirname, 'mydb');  
var db = level(dbPath);

module.exports = db;
```

And I want to be able to query the db, so my rudimentary try in `app.js` here:

```
var db = require('./db', {
  valueEncoding: 'json'
})

db.put('name', 'ID001')
db.put('name', 'ID002')
db.put('name', 'ID003')
db.put('name', 'ID004')
db.put('name', 'ID005')
db.put('name', 'ID006')
db.put('name', 'ID007')

db.createReadStream()
  .on('data', function (entry) {
    console.log(entry.value);
  })
```

I thought that I was only getting the last value in the db but after running it repeatedly I got output like this:

```
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
ID006
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
ID007
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
ID007
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
ID007
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
ID005
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
ID007
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
ID007
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
ID006
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
ID005
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
ID003
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
ID007
```

I just want to be able to either iterate through or query the db to see if a value needs to be put in there.

I have also tried using `.get` with the same sort of result

```
var db = require('./db', {
  valueEncoding: 'json'
})

db.put('name', 'ID001')
db.put('name', 'ID002')
db.put('name', 'ID003')
db.put('name', 'ID004')
db.put('name', 'ID005')
db.put('name', 'ID006')
db.put('name', 'ID007')

db.get('name', function(err, value) {  
  if (err) {
    return err;
  }
  console.log('value:', value);
});
```

Output...

```
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
value: ID007
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
value: ID004
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
value: ID005
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
value: ID007
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
value: ID003
spences10:~/workspace/level-db $ node app.js
value: ID007
```

Answer (score 1):

The `put` function is asynchronous and the code is executing the `put` operation several times sequentially. Then invoking `get` gives you the last value that was actually written. This is why you get different outputs every time you read run your code.

In the example from the [docs](https://github.com/Level/levelup) you can see that data is read in the callback of the put operation to make sure that it was actually written.

```
var levelup = require('levelup')

// 1) Create our database, supply location and options.
//    This will create or open the underlying LevelDB store.
var db = levelup('./mydb')

// 2) put a key & value
db.put('name', 'LevelUP', function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log('Ooops!', err) // some kind of I/O error

  // 3) fetch by key
  db.get('name', function (err, value) {
    if (err) return console.log('Ooops!', err) // likely the key was not found

    // ta da!
    console.log('name=' + value)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I did attempt to use this but it's only going to return what you have just put in the db? Am I misinterpreting this? So the idea is to enter the key+value then immediately get the value out you just put in?? I want to be able to see if there is an id, so `get('name', 'valueOfKeyValuePair' { console.log('yes that value is there') })

Comment: In the case of the example code yes, it is going to return exactly what you just put in. In the case of an actual application that runs as a service and performs `put` operations as it responds to user requests you can use `get` to check for the value of the key and you will get what the last value that was written.

Comment: I'm missing something conceptually then, I want to be able to add values into the database. At a later point I want to check to see if the value I have has been added, so in the example provided I have to add it to the database then check to see if I have just added it??

Comment: I don't want to get he last value written, I want to be able to query the database for any given id value, so query the level db to see if `ID004` is in there, not just to see if there was a value written, in the example I have given that would be `ID007` I'd like to know how to say "in this database, is there a `name` value of `ID003` in there" not "what was the last value written to the database"

Comment: Leveldb is a key-value store so if you need to query for the ids efficiently you should store the ids as the key and then use `get` for that key in order to find out id it was ever added.